# What distinguished a priest from other Levites?

Tags: priests, levites

II Chron. 29: “For the Levites were more conscientious to consecrate themselves than the priests.”

**What made a priest different from any other Levite?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All priests were Levites from the tribe of Levi, but not all Levites were priests. Only Levites from the family of Aaron were priests.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @oldhermit is correct but there are other important differences between priests and Levites.  Most important, at the Temple of Jerusalem, only priests descended were allowed to attend the sacrificial altar and offer sacrifice.

Num. 17:7

> But only you and your sons may serve as priests in connection with
> everything at the altar and inside the curtain. I am giving you the
> service of the priesthood as a gift. Anyone else who comes near the
> sanctuary is to be put to death.

On the other hand, Levites performed important functions as well:
According to the book of Chronicles, some Levite singers were highly esteemed as prophets (e.g., 2Chr 20:14). The Levites were also temple treasurers (1Chr 26:20-28) and controlled the order of the temple service (1Chr 24:6). They shared with priests the right to bless people (2Chr 30:27). Outside the temple, the Levites were administrators and officers (1Chr 23), judges (1Chr 26:29), warriors watching over both sides of the Jordan River (1Chr 26:30-32), court scribes (1Chr 24:6), and teachers of the people (2Chr 17:8). Chronicles also seems to indicate that the strict prohibition against their serving at the sacrificial the altar had been relaxed. (e.g., 2Chr 29:34; 2Chr 35:11) [source](https://blog.bibleodyssey.org/articles/priests-and-levites/#:)

It should be noted that the role of the Levites shifted over time. Prior to the reforms of Josiah, they often severed as priests at local altars, having been assigned to the various tribal jurisdictions. Their move to Jerusalem is apparently descried in the following passage:

2 Kings:23

> 8 He brought in all the priests from the cities of Judah, and then
> defiled, from Geba to Beer-sheba, the high places where they had
> offered incense. He also tore down the high places of the gates, which
> were at the entrance of the Gate of Joshua, governor of the city,
> north of the city gate. 9 The priests of the high places could not
> serve at the altar of the Lord in Jerusalem; but they ate unleavened
> bread among their brothers

Levites per se are not mentioned here, but the Book of Kings hardly mentions the Levites at all. As opposed to the pagan priests whom Josiah put to death, these priests (apparently Levites) are brought to Jerusalem and allowed to celebrate Passover (eat unleavened bread) with their Aaronic brothers, who likewise come from the Tribe of Levi. Previously these Levites had apparently served at local shines as well as famous high places like Gilgal, Beersheba, Gibeon and Bethel.

The Levites' role seems to have evolved after the Babylonian Exile. Thus, while the Book of Kings says little about them, Book of Chronicles goes into considerable detail about their functions. It also provides a more detailed timeline about the movement of the Levites from the countryside to the capital:

2 Chronicles 11:14

> (During the time of Jeroboam I) Levites left their assigned
> pasture lands and their holdings and came to Judah and Jerusalem,
> because Jeroboam and his sons rejected them as priests of the Lord.

2 Chronicles 23:2

> (Messengers) journeyed about Judah, gathering the Levites from all the
> cities of Judah... and they
> came to Jerusalem.

2 Chronicles 31

> Hezekiah re-established the divisions of the priests and the Levites
> according to their former divisions, assigning to each priest and
> Levite his proper service... 4 He also commanded the people living in
> Jerusalem to provide for the support of the priests and Levites, that
> they might firmly adhere to the law of the Lord.

Since the Levites were stationed in the provinces in earlier times, their role at the Temple seems to have been clarified gradually, and they became increasingly important there while remaining subservient to the Aaronic priests.

Today, Levitical lineages are preserved (or at least claimed) among Jews with names such as Levy, Ha-Levi, Levin, Levinson, Lowe, Lewinsky etc. Jewish names such as Cohen, Cohn, Kahn or Cowan often imply a Aaronic priestly lineage.

Comment: +1. Good thorough answer.